# Map on collection returns nil

Tags: ruby

I'm currently learning ruby and playing around with collections. I'm now stuck on a problem and need some help to understand why something works this way.

So, we have a simple array:

```
arr = ["cat", "dog", "pig", "goat"]
```

Now, I want to make every second elem uppercased and reversed. The first thing that I thought was the ternary:

```
modified = arr.each_with_index.map do |el, idx| 
    ((idx + 1) % 2 == 0) ? el.upcase.reverse : el
end
```

No big deal. But I played around and came up with another solution.

```
modified = arr.each_with_index.map do |el, idx| 
    el.upcase.reverse if (idx + 1) % 2 == 0
    el unless (idx + 1) % 2 == 0
end
```

It seems correct to me, but not to the interpreter.

With the ternary I get the result:

```
["cat", "GOD", "pig", "TAOG"]
```

But with the later approach:

```
["cat", nil, "pig", nil]
```

Can somebody, please, explain why the later doesn't work (it puts nill on every second elem)?

If I do it with regular if-else, it works again.

```
modified = arr.each_with_index.map do |el, idx| 
    if (idx + 1) % 2 == 0
        el.upcase.reverse
    else
        el
    end
end
```

How the regular if is different than the one-liners?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#map` would use the return value of the block passed in parameter to build the new array.

Since you are not using any `return` statement, it will always be the last expression evaluated.

In your first and third solutions, you always "hit" `el` or `el.upcase.reverse`

In your second solution, when `(idx + 1) % 2 == 0`, you are not doing anything, so you return simply `nil`.

Hope this helps.

*Note :* look at `Integer#odd?` and `Integer#even?`

Comment: Ahh, I get it! Thank you, floum! And the odd?/even? trick is nice and convenient. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
modified = arr.each_with_index.map do |el, idx| 
    el.upcase.reverse if (idx + 1) % 2 == 0
    el unless (idx + 1) % 2 == 0
end
```

This line `el unless (idx + 1) % 2 == 0 #=> nil` if the condition is satisfied. The array `["cat", nil, "pig", nil]` follows.

#### Another approach

```
arr.map.with_index { |str,i|  i.odd? ? str.upcase.reverse : str }
#=> ["cat", "GOD", "pig", "TAOG"]
```

Comment: The map.with_index is new to me. Seems cool. Thank you very much! :)